# How To Multiply Depending On Item Selected

Tags: c#, winforms

As you can see in the image below, in the middle DataGridView, you can see all the available fish species and their factors, e.g; Angler's Factor = 1.22.

If a user selects Angler in the combo box, and inputs how many he has caught, e.g User selects angler and inputs 5 into amount, then what's the easiest way to multiply combobox1 with the factor 1.22? and display it into the DataGridView on the right?

The factor should change depending on what the user selects in the combo box.

On the left of the image I included, you have an option to select which boat you want to view, When I switch boats, the 4 fish species from the previous boat, shows in the current boat, I do not know how to separate them
[image]

How I've Intialised:

```
 List<Fleet> boatList = new List<Fleet>();
        List<Fish> fishList = new List<Fish>();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();

        private Fleet currentBoat;
        private int boats = 0;

        private Fish currentFish;
        private int fishes = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Initialises
        string[] Species = new string[9] { "Angler", "Cod", "Haddock", "Hake", "Horse Mackerel", "Witches", "Plaice", "Skate and Rays", "Whiting" };
        decimal[] Tonnes = new decimal[9] { 5, 3, 4, 1, 0.5m, 3, 8, 1.8m, 7 };
        decimal[] Factor = new decimal[9] { 1.22m, 1.17m, 1.17m, 1.11m, 1.08m, 1.06m, 1.05m, 1.13m, 1.18m };
        int[] Kilograms = new int[9] { 5000, 3000, 4000, 1000, 500, 3000, 8000, 1800, 7000 };
        string[] weightVar = new string[2] { "KG", "T" };
        int[] FishAmount = new int[4];
        decimal[] Fished = new decimal[4];
```

What's inside my form_load():

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            LogoPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

            var species = new List<object>
            {
            new Fish(Species[0], Kilograms[0],0).GetSpecies(),
            new Fish(Species[1], Kilograms[1],0).GetSpecies(),
            new Fish(Species[2], Kilograms[2],0).GetSpecies(),
            new Fish(Species[3], Kilograms[3],0).GetSpecies(),
            new Fish(Species[4], Kilograms[4],0).GetSpecies(),
            new Fish(Species[5], Kilograms[5],0).GetSpecies(),
            new Fish(Species[6], Kilograms[6],0).GetSpecies(),
            new Fish(Species[7], Kilograms[7],0).GetSpecies(),
            new Fish(Species[8], Kilograms[8],0).GetSpecies()
            };

            Catch1ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<object>(species);
            Catch2ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<object>(species);
            Catch3ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<object>(species);
            Catch4ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<object>(species);

            Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            Catch2ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            Catch3ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            Catch4ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;   
        }
```

How I populate the DataGridView below:

```
private void BoatSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {                
            }
            //Boat
            string licenseVariable = BoatLicenseTextBox.Text;
            string intVariable = MaximumLoadTextBox.Text;
            //Fishes            
             FishAmount[0] = int.Parse(NumericAmount1.Text);
             FishAmount[1] = int.Parse(NumericAmount2.Text);
             FishAmount[2] = int.Parse(NumericAmount3.Text);
             FishAmount[3] = int.Parse(NumericAmount4.Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < Fished.Length; i++)
            {
                Fished[i] = FishAmount[i] * Factor[i];
            }

            //Error Checking
            if (BoatNameTextBox.Text == "" ||
                BoatLicenseTextBox.Text == "" ||
                MaximumLoadTextBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Input Name", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }                    
            else if (!Check(Catch1ComboBox, NumericAmount1) || !Check(Catch2ComboBox, NumericAmount2) ||
                !Check(Catch3ComboBox, NumericAmount3) || !Check(Catch4ComboBox, NumericAmount4))
                 {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                 }                
            else if ((Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1) || (Catch2ComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1 ) ||
                  (Catch3ComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1) || (Catch4ComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1))
                 {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select A Fish Specie", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                 }
            //Displays User Input Into DataGrid Boxes
            else
            {
                boatList.Add(new Fleet(BoatNameTextBox.Text, licenseVariable, intVariable));

                fishList.Add(new Fish(Catch1ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), Fished[0], Kilograms[0]));
                fishList.Add(new Fish(Catch2ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), Fished[1], Kilograms[1]));
                fishList.Add(new Fish(Catch3ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), Fished[2], Kilograms[2]));
                fishList.Add(new Fish(Catch4ComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), Fished[3], Kilograms[3]));

                currentBoat = boatList[boats];
                currentFish = fishList[fishes];                

                //Reset Boat Boxes
                BoatNameTextBox.Text = "";
                BoatLicenseTextBox.Text = "";
                MaximumLoadTextBox.Text = "";
                //Reset Combo Boxes
                Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
                Catch2ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
                Catch3ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
                Catch4ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
                //Reset Numeric Value Boxes
                NumericAmount1.Value = 0;
                NumericAmount2.Value = 0;
                NumericAmount3.Value = 0;
                NumericAmount4.Value = 0;
                //Add-On To Boat List
                boats++;

                //Add Boat To Combo Box
                var last = boatList.Last(); // using System.Linq;
                BoatSelector.Items.Add(last.GetboatName() + " - " + last.GetboatLicense());
                BoatSelector.SelectedIndex +=1;
            }
        }
        private void BoatSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < boatList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (BoatSelector.SelectedIndex == i)
                {
                    dt2.Rows.Clear();
                    dt3.Rows.Clear();
                    dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { boatList[i].GetboatName(), boatList[i].GetboatLicense(), boatList[i].GetmaximumLoad() });
                    dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { fishList[0].GetSpecies(), fishList[0].GetFished() + weightVar[0], fishList[i].GetQouta()});
                    dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { fishList[1].GetSpecies(), fishList[1].GetFished() + weightVar[0], fishList[i].GetQouta()});
                    dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { fishList[2].GetSpecies(), fishList[2].GetFished() + weightVar[0], fishList[i].GetQouta()});
                    dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { fishList[3].GetSpecies(), fishList[3].GetFished() + weightVar[0], fishList[i].GetQouta()});
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You should try to reduce your problem to [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JustinLessard Sorry, my question was, when a user selects an item in a combo box, how would I change the factor it uses? and display it into my datagrid on the left

Comment: Throwing this much code at your audience without a clear problem will attract downvotes.  I'm not a downvoter, but I will vote to close this as too broad.

Comment: @UnboundPhantom  Since you have two different array list `string[] Species` and `decimal[] Factor` you can get the value and calculate in following way. **Step 1:** Use `Combobox.SelectedIndexChanged` event to get the Index Value of the Item (Fish name) from `combobox`. **Step 2:** Now get the value from `decimal[] Factor` array list using the Index value which will return the Factor value of corresponding Fish selected.